# Check if animation has finished playing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I check if a **specific** animation has finished playing in Unity, then execute an action? [C#] I am not using an animator.

Comment: Not sure how your addition of "I am not using an animator" invalidates Andrea's response, since `IsPlaying` is a property of `Animation`, not `Animator`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/52005/destroy-game-object-after-animation.html

To execute an action from the animation editor...

-Create a script with a simple public function that will destroy the object. e.g.

```
public class Destroyable : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public void DestroyMe() 
    { 
        Destroy(gameObject); 
    } 
}
```

-Add that script to the animated object you want to destroy.

-In the animation editor, move the animation scrubber to the end of the animation.

-Use the 'Add Event' button in the animation toolbar

-Select 'DestroyMe' from the function drop-down in the Edit Animation Event dialog.

-Now your animation should play, run the 'DeleteMe' function, and destroy the object/do your action.

I've used this method a few times, comes in handy for certain things in animations :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check [Animation.IsPlaying](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.IsPlaying.html) value.

From the docs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Animation anim;
    void Start() {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    }
    void OnMouseEnter() {
        if (!anim.IsPlaying("mouseOverEffect"))
            anim.Play("mouseOverEffect");

    }
}
```

Comment: @user5497945 Can you explain why? This seems like a reasonable answer, if you can't use it for some valid reason, please edit your question and add why.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Andrea said in his post : [Animation-IsPlaying](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation-isPlaying.html) is pretty much what you need since you don't use Animator. Check [Animation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) to see other sweet stuff you can use.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Animation anim;
    void Start()
{
   anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
}

//In update or in another method you might want to check
if(!anim.isPlaying("StringWithAnimationClip") //or anim.clip.name
   //Do Something
}
```

You can also force stop the animation with anim.Stop();

Now you commented that you don't want to use isPlaying() so if you can please elaborate I will edit my post.